# Sequelize erro: [...].belongsToMany([...]) requires through option, pass either a string or a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js, electron

Estou importando models usando o autoloader (index.js) do sequelize. Um model AccessLevel tem um relacionamento com o model Menu (N: N), através do model AccessLevelHasMenu.

**O que deveria acontecer?**
Ao importar esse autloader ele deveria chamar as models e injetar a conexão do sequelize nelas e retorná-las.

**O que está acontecendo**
Ao importar o autoloader (`models/index.js`) a seguinte mensagem de erro é exibida:
`SequelizeAssociationError: AccessLevel.belongsToMany(Menu) requires through option, pass either a string or a model`

OBS: Estou utilizando essa stack com electron-webpack, nodejs v12 e sequelize "^5.21.7"

**AccessLevel Model**

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const AccessLevel = sequelize.define('AccessLevel', {
    idAccessLevel: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    label: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {});
  AccessLevel.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    console.log("É AQUI ---------")
    console.log(models)
    AccessLevel.belongsToMany(models.Menu, {
      trough: "AccessLeveHasMenu",
      foreignKey: "idAccessLevel"
    })
  };
  return AccessLevel;
};
```

**Menu Model**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Menu = sequelize.define('Menu', {
  idMenu: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  label: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {});
Menu.associate = function (models) {
  // associations can be defined here
  Menu.belongsToMany(models.AccessLevel, {
    trough: "AccessLevelHasMenu",
    foreignKey: "idMenu"
  })
};
return Menu;
}
```

**AccessLevelHasMenu Model**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const AccessLevelHasMenu = sequelize.define('AccessLevelHasMenu', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    idAccessLevel: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    idMenu: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {});
  AccessLevelHasMenu.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    AccessLevelHasMenu.belongsTo(models.AccessLevel, {
      foreignKey: "idAccessLevel"
    })
    AccessLevelHasMenu.belongsTo(models.Menu, {
      foreignKey: "idMenu"
    })
  };
  return AccessLevelHasMenu;
};
```

**Autoloader (models/index.js)**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/database.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    console.log(file)
    const model = require("./" + file)(sequelize, DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, você colocou trough ao invés de **through** no seu  AccessLevel Model e  Menu Model,  provavelmente agora dara certo, espero que ajude.